# java gui using the split function to display in a text area

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, frontend

Hi im trying to use the split function within a textarea so it will only display certain information to the user, currently I tried to use the typical method used in general programming into the GUI interface however I believe I implemented it incorrectly.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    String st;
    String[] setdate = null;
    String[] submission = null;
    String[] title = null;
    String[] value = null;
    try 
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader (filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        jTextArea1.read(br, null);
        br.close();
        jTextArea1.requestFocus();

    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(st); 
        if(st.contains("TITLE")) 
            title = st.split(":");
        if(st.contains("DATE SET"))
            setdate = st.split(":");                
        if(st.contains("SUBMISSION"))
            submission = st.split(":");
        if(st.contains("VALUE:"))
            value = st.split(":");
    }                  
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, e);
    }
}
```

[cuurent display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3kPq.png)

Comment: what is your actual question? ok, you split the value, then what?

Comment: Your error also has a complete stacktrace. include it in your question

Comment: @Stultuske display it within the jtextarea

Answer (score 1):

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader (filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
jTextArea1.read(br, null);
br.close();
jTextArea1.requestFocus();

while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Currently you open the `BufferedReader`, read something with it and close it directly. Then again you want to read again using the same reader you just closed `br.readLine()`.

`br.close();` should be done in a `finally` block

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
    jTextArea1.read(br, null);
    jTextArea1.requestFocus();

    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(st);
        if (st.contains("TITLE"))
            title = st.split(":");
        if (st.contains("DATE SET"))
            setdate = st.split(":");
        if (st.contains("SUBMISSION"))
            submission = st.split(":");
        if (st.contains("VALUE:"))
            value = st.split(":");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: i dont think the close file in the finally block would work

Comment: Why not? I adjusted any scope issues which might arise

Comment: exception IOexception is never thrown in the body of the corresponding try statement, and i think br is still out of scope of the try block

Comment: yup br.close after finally is still an issue :/

Comment: then you haven't updated the declaration of `BufferedReader br = null;` which is even before the first `try`. I now updated it to `try-with-resource` which eleminates all the problems

Comment: yeah if i do that br.close(); dereferences possible null pointers

Comment: just use the newest version and there are no problems at all

Answer (score 0):

```
jTextArea1.read(br, null);
```

The point of using the read(...) method of the JTextArea is to read data from a file and add the data to the text area.

So after invoking that method all the data in the file has already been read.

If you want to parse the data BEFORE adding the data to the text area, then you should NOT be using the read(...) method. Instead you just read each line of data from the file and then you use the `append(...)` method of the JTextArea to add the data.

```
if (st.contains("TITLE"))
    title = st.split(":");
```

Also, I don't know what the format of your file is but what do you expect that code to do. Every time you read a line containing `TITLE` you create a new array. I suspect instead you should create the array to get the data and then use the `append(...)` method to add the data to the text area.

But without a clear requirement we are only guessing.